# What is the distribution of $Y$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, generating-functions

[image]

please help me . what is distribution of Y?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{1-\alpha+\alpha s}=\frac{1}{1-\alpha} \frac{1}{1+\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha} s}$ (unless $\alpha=1$). Do you know how to get a series for $\frac{1}{1+x}$ in powers of $x$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.  You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\alpha=0$ then $G_Y=1$, so $Y$ is a constant variable of value $0$. If $\alpha\ne0$,$$G_Y=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\frac{1}{1+\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}s}=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-\alpha)^n}{(1-\alpha)^{n+1}}s^n$$isn't the PGF of any distribution due to its including negative coefficients.